# TypeScript 2.4.1 -> fontWeight -> Type 'number' is not assignable to type '"inherit" | 400 |

Tags: javascript, css, typescript, material-design, material-ui

I get this error when I try to set `fontWeight` in TypeScript:

```
Types of property 'test' are incompatible.
    Type '{ fontWeight: number; }' is not assignable to type 'Partial<CSSProperties>'.
        Types of property 'fontWeight' are incompatible.
            Type 'number' is not assignable to type '"inherit" | 400 | "initial" | "unset" | "normal" | "bold" | "bolder" | "lighter" | 100 | 200 | 30...'.
```

Even though `400` is a correct number it could be any number and therefore I get the error as I understand it. I can track this error to React.CSSProperties that specifies that `fontWeight` should look like this:

```
fontWeight?: CSSWideKeyword | "normal" | "bold" | "bolder" | "lighter" | 100 | 200 | 300 | 400 | 500 | 600 | 700 | 800 | 900;
```

What I can't do is set `test: React.CSSProperties`

```
const styles = (theme: Theme) => ({
    test: {
        fontWeight: 400
    }
});
```

I can do it like this but it is not how Material UI handles classes.

```
const test: React.CSSProperties = {
    fontWeight: 400
}
```

Complete code:

```
import * as React from "react";
import * as ReactDOM from "react-dom";
import * as ReactRouter from "react-router";
import { withRouter } from "react-router-dom";
import { withStyles } from 'material-ui/styles';
import Badge from 'material-ui/Badge';
import Grid from 'material-ui/Grid';
import { Theme } from 'material-ui/styles';

interface IState {
    userName: string;
}

interface IProps {
    history?: any;
    classes?: any;
}

const styles = (theme: Theme) => ({
    test: {
        fontWeight: 400
    }
});

class Menu extends React.Component<IProps, IState> {
    constructor(props: IProps) {
        super(props);
        this.state = {
            userName: localStorage.userName ? 'userName ' + localStorage.userName : "",
        }
    }
    render() {
        return (
            <div>
                <Grid container spacing={24}>
                    <Grid item xs={12} className={this.props.classes.test}>
                    <span>Test</test>
                    </Grid>
                </Grid>
            </div>
        );
    }
}
```

Answer (score 16, accepted):

Solved it:

```
const styles = (theme: Theme) => ({
    test: {
        fontWeight: 400
    } as React.CSSProperties
});
```

Comment: Adding a return type for your function instead of casting it to the type, would allow the compiler to verify the type instead of forcing it.

Comment: @JohanLindskogen The Theme is from Material-UI that itself uses JSS. The Theme is expecting React.CSSProperties and will give the incompatible exception above otherwise. It has to be set for each new object in the method.

Comment: Oh, I see. Material-UI now recommends using the `createStyles` function btw, https://material-ui.com/guides/typescript/

Answer (score 7):

Currently accepted answer for this question is just a workaround. The proper way to solve this problem is using `createStyles` function from Material-UI.

```js
const styles = (theme: Theme) => createStyles({
    test: {
        fontWeight: 400
    }
});
```

See the [material UI documentation](https://mui.com/styles/advanced/#using-createstyles-to-defeat-type-widening).